# Cannot convert UploadFile to bytearray

Tags: python, image-processing, file-upload, fastapi, bytesio

I have the following function for reading a file:

```
def read_image(image_encoded):
    im = bytearray(image_encoded)
    pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(im))
    return pil_image
```

The function is called here:

```
@app.post('/api/predict')
async def predict_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # Read Image File
    img = read_image(file)
    
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    print(img_array.shape)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis

    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = predictions[0]
    return score
```

However, the 'UploadFile' object can't be converted to a bytearray and throws the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert 'UploadFile' object to bytearray
```

I have tried without converting to bytearray but a bytes-like object is required. Here is the error if I try it without converting to bytearray:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'UploadFile'
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Call `read` on the file-like object (`file`) to read its contents? `img = read_image(file.read())` should work if you expect the content of the file and not the file like object itself.

Comment: This worked for reading the content of the file, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're expecting the file content, you can call `.read()` on the `UploadFile` object. It's a file-like object, so `file.read()` will give you the content just as it would for a regular file.

```
img = read_image(file.read())
```

.. should do what you want.